# How to pass a value for cron job among 3 seperate java processes?

Tags: java, cron

I have cron job running on my server every morning that essentially runs three different java programs(all having a main method) in succession one after the other let me name them as **P1**, **P2** and **P3**.

The first process **P1** and the last process **P3** are quite fast, but the second process **P2** comsumes a lot of time sometime(sometimes it runs for more than a day) as it does some complex business logic.

The business calculation as very complex and based on periodicity of the clients to be involved in that days process.

Lets say on **DAY 1** I have to process **1 million clients** as they are enrolled for **DAY 1**

and on **DAY 2** I have less number of clients say **1000 clients**.

Now when the second process **P2** is running, it stored the client processing details in the database with the status as **PENDING** as it will be changed to **SUCCESS** by the last process **p3** finishes.

Now my problem is this:

***ON DAY 1***

1. Process **P1** gets completed on the same day and process **P2** starts after it.

***ON DAY 2***

1. Process **P2** started on DAY 1 is still running and entering the details in the database.
2. All the process **P1**, **P2** and **P3** starts for DAY 2 and
   completes all their work for DAY 2.

So when the last process **P3** for DAY 2 is completed all the previous entries in the database entered by process **P2** of DAY 1 with the PENDING status are updated to SUCCESS, even though the last process **P3** for DAY 1 has not started yet.

Now I don't want this to happen, that is DAY 2 process **P3** updating the status of entries entered in the database by DAY 1 process **P2**.

I am trying to determine how to solve this issue.

One thing I thought would be put up dates with the database entries, but then how would the process **P3** know which dates to pick up for updation.

I know this seems a lot of confusion. But please let me know if I can clarify more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the simple approach is to have P1 test / create a flag file, and P3 delete the flag file when it completes.  Actually it is probably best to do this in the wrapper script that runs P1 / P2 / P3.

One complication you need to deal with is that possibility that something fails, leaving you with a flag file ... but no running P1/P2/P3.  One trick you can use to deal with this is to store the PID of (say) the shell that's running the wrapper script in the flag file.  Then check that the previous script is still alive using `kill 0 $THE_PID_FROM_THE_FILE`.  (The `kill` command with signal zero tests if a process exists.)

Comment: can you please guide me on dealing this inside the wrapper?

Comment: @Abu - specifically, what are you asking?

Comment: you mentioned that it is probably best to do it in wrapper script, I am thinking to create a date string and pass it to all three process for a particular day and store this date inside the database so that I can distinguish between records for particular day, so is possible inside the wrapper script or is there any other way I can achieve this.

Comment: You can create a date string in a script.  Read `man 1 date`.  Also you should probably read a tutorial on writing shell scripts.